# Subconsulta para contar resultados

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, php7, mariadb, subconsultas

**Les platico mi inconveniente, espero me puedan orientar:**

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(id_usuario) AS totalUsers FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT u.id_user AS id_usuario FROM users u
    INNER JOIN user_hotel uh ON u.id_user = uh.id_usuario
    INNER JOIN restaurante r ON uh.id_hotel = r.id_hotel
    INNER JOIN user_restaurante ur ON r.id_restaurante = ur.id_restaurante
    WHERE uh.id_usuario = 2
) AS prueba;
```

en la cual obtengo el, id único no repetitivo de la tabla users que está vinculada a la tabla *user_hotel* que a su vez el *id_hotel* está asociada con el restaurante y esta última a la de *user_restaurante* y como resultado me trae 1 cuando no deberia ser asi me deberia traer más usuarios.

Mi objetivo es traer todos los usuarios vinculados del hotel 1 (ejemplo) sumado de los usuarios que estén vinculados a los restaurantes que pertenezcan al hotel 1.

estas son las tablas vinculadas:

users
[image: users]

user_hotel
[image: user_hotel]

user_restaurante
[image: user_restaurante]

restaurantes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: prueba algo como esto SELECT COUNT(ID_USUARIO) FROM USER_HOTEL JOIN USERS ON USERS.ID_USER = USER_HOTEL.ID_USUARIO WHERE ID_HOTEL=1

Comment: Eso te devolverá la cantidad de usuarios que hay en el hotel 1

Comment: Si quieres ver los usuarios vinculados a el restaurante del hotel 1,  sería algo como SELECT COUNT(ID_USUARIO) FROM USER_RESTAURANTE JOIN RESTAURANTES ON USER_RESTAURANTE.ID_RESTAURANTE = RESTAURANTES.ID_RESTAURANTE WHERE ID_HOTEL=1

Comment: Gracias estas consultas me ayudaron a tener los resultados más exactos, pero que pasa si quiero traer los usuarios vinculados del restaurante del hotel 1 pero donde en user_hotel el id_usuario = 1, sin importar el user_hotel tendría que traermos el total de users_restaurante por la union del hotel